# Is there any benefit at all for explicitly discarding a value via (void) in C

Tags: c++, c

One of the uses of the `void` keyword in C/C++ is to discard the value of an expression:

```
(void) expr;
```

Is there any benefit at all of the above construct except to avoid "unused parameter" warnings like the below?

```
void foo(int x, int y) {
  (void) x;
  //..
}
```

Comment: No, suppressing warnings is the only reason for it.

Comment: FWIW, it's not even needed to prevent the warning, at least in C++.  The function could be `void foo(int, int y)  { ... }` and there will be no warning for the first parameter.

Comment: C++ learned a lot from C. One of the many things was `void foo(int , int y)` to squelch unused parameter warnings. Yeah. What he ^ said. So here's a bit of value-add: It can be worth your time to `void foo(int /* x */, int y)` to leave a few hints about what was omitted for future programmers (and future you).

Comment: Similar to warnings, but it also signals to future readers that you intentionally discard the value.

Comment: @Barmar if you are a dev who likes -Werror (as we all should - ducks from the incoming flame wars) then suppressing warnings is a major benefit

Comment: @pm100 I didn't mean to imply that this isn't a useful warning, but the OP asked if there's some benefit other than this.

Comment: @Barmar - aha yes, I only read the title not the body. My bad

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the standards. Pick one language and delete the other tag. And do not pick C, because somebody has already answered for C++. If you want to ask about C, ask a new question. Questions about fine points of the languages often have different answers for the different languages, and tagging both confuses things.

Comment: The cast to `void` is sometimes used to indicate the code is intentionally discarding the return value of a function call (not just unused variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C++

Because `void` is not a reference to object type, the result of this cast is a prvalue even if the input was an lvalue.  In C++ this is stated in [`[expr.cast]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#1).

Based on that fact, it should force an *lvalue-to-rvalue* conversion on the expression.  For ordinary variables, such a conversion with discarded result has no side effects and can and will be removed by the optimizer, however for `volatile` lvalues, that conversion is a volatile side-effect and cannot be discarded.

However, there's a detail in [`[expr.static_cast]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#6) that throws a fly into the ointment:

> Any expression can be explicitly converted to type cv void, in which case it becomes a discarded-value expression ([expr.prop]).

Thus the result prvalue didn't come from converting the expression, it is simply a `void` prvalue created out of thin air.  The expression still isn't forced to undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (but it might, according to the rules of discarded-value expressions).

So in the end there is no effect at all from a cast to void, except possibly changing your compiler's warning heuristics.

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of change this could make to the generated code? Maybe use a godbolt link?

Comment: @Barmar: https://godbolt.org/z/54GWvez8E

Comment: This does not evince any benefit for casting to void. For a volatile object `x`, `x;` has the same effect as `(void) x;`, and a compiler should not issue a warning for an unused value since `x` is volatile. So the cast accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Better demo: https://godbolt.org/z/MxaPvKfbG    @EricPostpischil you are correct it doesn't produce an rvalue conversion, which I find very surprising.  It does produce a different warning, though.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ahh, there are two rules in the Standard which come in conflict with each other.  According to [expr.cast/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#1) the result of the cast is a prvalue, hence lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is expected.  According to [expr.static_cast/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#6) it is a discarded-value expression just like a statement expression.

Comment: OP tagged both C and C++. Answers should state which they are answering for.